# Did any other country aside the Netherlands allow children access to some sort of physician-assisted death?

Tags: law, international

> In 2000, the Netherlands became the first country to allow children
> access to physician-assisted death. In that country, there is an
> age-based regime based on the presumption of evolving capacity. This
> means that children between 12 and 16 years of age must be able to
> express their views, interests and wishes in support of
> physician-assisted death, but still require parental consent, whereas
> children between 16 and 18 years of age can consent to their own
> physician- assisted death without parental consent, although their
> parents retain the right to participate in the discussions leading to
> a decision.

https://www.ourcommons.ca/Content/Committee/421/JUST/Brief/BR8301283/br-external/UNICEFCanada-e.pdf

Did any other country aside the Netherlands allow children access to some sort of physician-assisted death? It seems in 2000, the Netherlands legalized children access to physician-assisted death, so I was wondering if any other country chose to legalize it besides the Netherlands.

Comment: This seems like you are leaning a lot of important details out of your question such as what is the criteria for it to be allowed to happen.

Comment: It might be interesting for you to know that the Netherlands have generally been at the forefront of the right-to-die, even compared to other very liberal Western European states.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the topic of suicide requires a more nuanced treatment.  We don't want to be a resources that some teenager, looking to commit a suicide, stumbles on and decides to take a road trip.

Comment: Voting not to close - It's a simple question that can be factually answered - what other  countries legally allow terminally ill children or teenagers to opt for death? Sure, this is an uncomfortable and controversial topic. But the question isn't against any community guidelines that I know of.

Comment: Voting not to close. @wrod's idea that you can simply take a roadtrip to the Netherlands, as a minor, and then find a physician there that's going to help you with a suicide, that idea is beyond insane. Spreading such misconceptions is way more harmful than this question.

Comment: Belgium allows emancipated minors - does that count?